# removing empty json objects from jsonarray android

Tags: android, json

I am not able to remove empty `JSON` object from array android

```
"value":
    [
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {},
      {"value":"hshdhd","id":"78232102"}
    ]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to deserialize the json ?

Comment: i am not desrializing i am passing to backend,so need to passs without empty jsonobjects

Comment: ok, maybe you can deserialize it to a JsonArray and then remove the JsonObjects that are empty in the array.

Comment: in that case how are you serializing it? post that code

Comment: If you serialize this json to send it, then the process must be done before serializing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove empty Json Object by just checking length of the object.

Please see below example

```
try {

    // This is your json strinh
    String json = "{\"value\":[{},{},{},{},{},{\"value\":\"hshdhd\",\"id\":\"78232102\"}]}";

    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(json);

    JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(jObj.getString("value"));

    Log.w("Sample", "Json Array 1 >> " + jArr);

    JSONArray jArr2 = new JSONArray();

    for(int i = 0 ; i < jArr.length() ; i++) {

        JSONObject jObjIn = new JSONObject(jArr.getString(i));

        if(jObjIn.length() > 0)
            jArr2.put(jObjIn);
    }

    Log.w("Sample", "Json Array 2 >> " + jArr2);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

> Output:

[image]